# Grails dependency injection and factories

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

How can I to use the grails/spring dependency injection on my application for to eradicate the factories?

If I have an abstract ModelCalculator and I want to create a concrete ModelCalculator (ModelCalculatorStrict, ModelCalculatorFuzze, etc) How can I to use spring dependency injection to evict create a ModelCalculatorFactory?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use for a [service](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/services.html). You could run the command `grails create-service com.app.ModelCalculator` to create a service in the grails-app/services directory. Then to inject the dependency in your classes, add `def modelCalculator` to the class.

Comment: I know services, but what when you service should to change on context. What if your modelCalculator should to use an algorithm in some cases and another in other cases. And finally, how you can inject new behavior in future. Dependency injection should be the answer but how to implement it with grails.